# Is my proof using induction complete?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I need to prove a statement involving two variables over non-negative integers. That is $P(a, b)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$

I did the following steps

1.$ P(a, 0)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$

2.$ P(a, 1)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$

3.$ P(a, b-1) \land P(a, b) \implies P(a+1, b)$

Is my proof complete? Any statement to prove more than the statements provided?

Comment: Your proof never induct on $b$.  So, I don't think it is complete.  But then, the context is very important.  What exactly are you trying to prove?

Comment: I am trying to prove a property of binomial coefficients. Instead of using combinatorial formula, I want to prove using MI. $\binom{a}{b}$.

Comment: Then, I suggest one more step: $P(0,b)$ for all $b\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  With this step, your proof should be complete.  (Note that $\binom{0}{b}=1$ if $b=0$, and $\binom{0}{b}=0$ for all integers $b>0$.)

Comment: 1.$ P(a, 0)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$

2.$ P(a, 1)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$

3. $P(0,b)$ for all $b \in \mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}$

4.$ P(a, b-1) \land P(a, b) \implies P(a+1, b)$

Comment: Without (3) in your comment above, you have no way of making incremental changes in $b$.  Now, with (3), you will be fine.

Comment: Then I think that 3,4 are enough for complete proof! NO need for 1,2?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  Those two steps should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not complete. How, for example, do you get that $P(0,2)$ from any of this?

You either need to show that $P(0,b)$ for any $b$, and then induct over the $a$, or show that $P(a, b-1) \land P(a,b) \Rightarrow P(a,b+1)$